# What is "the" in "You will live the closer to the grace of God..."?

Tags: grammar

> You will live **the closer** to the grace of God for your full dedication to the Bible. (George Smith)

What is this "the closer"? Why "the?"

Comment: Google is telling me: `No results found for "You will live the closer to the grace of God"`. It could be a typo; perhaps the author meant: _"You will live **all** the closer to the grace of God..."_, as the phrase "all the closer" is idiomatic.

Comment: @user10365, you should put those references **in your question**.

Comment: Also, when you add these links to your question, please try to use *working* links.

Comment: My comment now appears strange because you deleted the one I was replying to.  The reason I wrote it is because you **did** post a link, but it was broken.

Comment: So I see. http://www.victorianlondon.org/etexts/dickens/mutual-0007.shtml

Comment: The owner of the face has no cravat on, and has opened his tumbled shirt-collar to work with the more ease.

Answer (score 3):

> **the** *ad-form*<sup>COMPARATIVE</sup> **for** *nominal*

(I use *ad-form* to designate an adjectival or adverbial).

This is a literary construction which you probably will not encounter as often in conversation as, say, fifty years ago. It signifies that *nominal* is the cause of *ad-form* being <sup>COMPARATIVE</sup>: that is, more whatever-it-is.

> She went the more willingly for his accompanying her. = *She was more willing to go because he accompanied her*.
>
> A long time ago we didn’t have this social networking and I must say I was the happier for it. = *I was happier because we didn’t have social networking.*
>
> We will certainly catch up to them tomorrow—and travel all the faster for a night’s rest. = *We will travel faster because we will get a night’s rest.*

Your author is saying that your dedication to the Bible will cause you to live closer to the grace of God.

Comment: But the construction sited in OP is a bit different to the one you mentioned in your post. OP says ** the closer *to* the grace of God**, but you say there should be a ***for*** instead of ***to***. So what is the difference?

Comment: @Man_From_India I think it's **the** *closer to the grace of God* **for** *your full dedication to the Bible*.  As it happens, *closer* has a complement in this particular example, but the *for* is still there, just a little bit later on.